# What's the timeline of Commodore diskette drives?

Tags: history, floppy-disk, commodore, disk-drive, commodore-pet

Commodore produced a number of different floppy diskette drive units, both 8" and 5.25", over the course of its history. Can someone provide a chronological list of the drives, their release dates, brief specifications, and ideally links to further information for each drive? I'm particularly interested in drive units predating the 1541.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can get a relative ordering by looking at DOS versions for the drives.

**IEEE-488 drives**

- 2040 - first drive, 5.25"x2@170K, 1979, DOS 1.0
- 3040 - 5.25"x2@170k in Europe, 1979, DOS 1.2
- 4040 - 5.25"x2@170k, 1980, DOS 2.0
- 2031 - 5.25"x1@170k, 1980, DOS 2.0
- 4031 - 5.25"x2@170k, 1980, DOS 2.0
- 8050 - 5.25"x2@521k, 1980, DOS 2.5
- 8250 - 5.25"x2@1042k (double-sided), 1981, DOS 2.7
- 8060 - 8"x1@750k, 1984, DOS 2.7
- 8061 - 8"x2@800k, 1984, DOS 2.7
- 8062 - 8"x2@1.6M, 1984, DOS 2.7
- SFD-1001 - 5.25"x1@1M, 1984, DOS 2.7
- 8280 - 8"x2@1M, 1984, DOS 3.0

**Serial drives**

- 1540 - 5.25"x1@170k, 1980, DOS 2.6
- 1541 - 5.25"x1@170k, 1982 as VIC-1541 with VIC colors, DOS 2.6
- 1551 - 5.25"x1@170k, 1984, DOS 2.6
- 1570 - 5.25"x1@170k, 1985, DOS 3.0
- 1571 - 5.25"x1@340k (double-sided), 1985, DOS 3.0
- 1572 - 5.25"x1@340k, 1985, DOS 3.0
- 1541C - 5.25"x1@170k, 1986, DOS 2.6
- 1581 - 3.5"x1@800k, 1987, DOS 10.0
- 1541-II - 5.25"x1@170k, 1988, DOS 2.6

There were also other compatible drives like the MSD-2.

Some useful pages:

- [cbmsrc github](https://github.com/mist64/cbmsrc)
- [PET index - DOS ROMs](http://www.6502.org/users/andre/petindex/drives/roms/index.html#dos1x)
- [Wikipedia template for Commodore disk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:Commodore_disk_drives)
- [Secret World of Commodore drives](https://www.floodgap.com/retrobits/ckb/secret/periph.html)
- [cbmmuseum](http://cbmmuseum.kuto.de/floppy.html) floppy pages (in German)
- (edit) [Canonical List of Commodore Computer Equipment](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.sys.cbm/9-Gntfcc9Rs/0Ps_DqRyrIwJ)

Comment: Are you sure about the 1541 and the 1541C? Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commodore_1541) gives the release years as 1982 and 1986, which is also (a) what I remember, and which (b) also ligns up with the C-64C being released in 1986.

Comment: I think you're right. Corrected.

Comment: Didn't the Vic-20 come out in 1981? If so then I imagine the 1540 did too; it's the first machine with the Commodore serial bus unless I'm mistaken.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the VIC supported the C2N tape drive only at first (not much need for a disk with 3.5k) - which agrees with http://cbmmuseum.kuto.de/floppy_vc1540.html

Comment: Was the 1572 `x2@340k`?

Comment: I didn't include the 1572 because it was never released. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commodore_1571 - "Commodore announced at the 1985 Consumer Electronics Show a dual-drive version of the 1571, to be called the Commodore 1572, but quickly canceled it...." There were quite a few drives that got announced but never made it into production.

Answer (score 4):

In addition, here are the Amiga external floppy drives:

- 1010 - 3.5"x1 @ 880k, 1985
- 1020 - 5.25"x1 @ 440k, 1986
- 1011 - 3.5"x1 @ 880k, 1989
- 1411 - 3.5"x1 @ 880k, 1991

Note that although the 1020 was capable of reading and writing 440k on a single-sided floppy, it was intended to work with IBM-formatted disks up to 360k.

Comment: Didn't the Amiga launch in 1985? If so then 1984 for the 1010 probably isn't right?

Comment: Yeah.  It may have been announced in 1984 but release was obviously in 1985.  Good catch.

Comment: I seem to remember the 1020 being available in 85, as we got one with our first 1000, which was an "as soon as we can!" buy.

Comment: I have read elsewhere that the Amiga 1020 was 440k for Amiga and 360k for PC format disks.

Comment: @Geo... Good catch, it appears to have been possible but it also sounds like it was rarely used that way.